# My website has some empty spacing I can't get rid of

Tags: html, css, web

I am developing a very simple website and I have encountered an error in the layout. I have a random to the right of my webpage that isn't visible and that you can scroll to and I don't know how to get rid of it. There really isn't anything going on in my HTMl but here is the CSS of my project.

```
    @import url(http://nicholastodor.com/sf/usesf.css);

html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    background-color: black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#developmentTitle {
    margin: auto;
    font-family: "Avenir Next";
    color: lightgrey;
    font-size: 19px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    left: 13%;
    top: 103%;
    position: relative;
    -ms-transform: translate(0,-100%); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: translate(0,-100%); /* Safari */
    transform: translate(0,-100%);
}

#development {
    margin: auto;
    font-family: "Avenir Next";
    color: lightgrey;
    font-size: 15px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    left: 33%;
    top: 114%;
    position: relative;
    -ms-transform: translate(0,-116%); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: translate(0,-116%); /* Safari */
    transform: translate(0,-116%);  
}

#aboutMe {
    margin: auto;
    font-family: "Avenir Next";
    color: lightgrey;
    font-size: 15px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    left: 33%;
    top: 117%;
    position: relative;
    -ms-transform: translate(0,-116%); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: translate(0,-116%); /* Safari */
    transform: translate(0,-116%);  
}

#aboutMeTitle {
    margin: auto;
    font-family: "Avenir Next";
    color: lightgrey;
    font-size: 19px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    left: 13%;
    top: 100%;
    position: relative;
    -ms-transform: translate(0,-100%); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: translate(0,-100%); /* Safari */
    transform: translate(0,-100%);
}

#beginningTitle {
    margin: auto;
    font-family: "Avenir";
    color: lightgrey;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    top: 50%;
    position: relative;
    -ms-transform: translate(0,-50%); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: translate(0,-50%); /* Safari */
    transform: translate(0,-50%);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but we cannot really help without the additional markup (the html). Best is if you create a fiddle for us to understand your issue: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: "I have a random to the right of my webpage" What does this mean?

Comment: Please put it on jsfiddle and at least include the HTML code too. CSS is useless without the HTML, nobody would know how you have organized the elements on the HTML.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you are translating a lot of things, my guess is that some of it is going outside the view of screen,

use `overflow: hidden` over parent of these `translated` elements see if it works

or else maybe some default CSS is being applied, you can reset that for `HTML`, `BODY` etc

or check your `DOM` by [Pesticide for chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pesticide-for-chrome/bblbgcheenepgnnajgfpiicnbbdmmooh) for different elements you have (it will give them multi-colored borders for testing) and see which one is actually going out of screen, and handle it.

We can help you better if you upload you markup too, or even better use JSbin or JSFiddle and we will edit it to how it should be and give it back,

Answer (score 0):

The browser's default CSS sets some margin to the `body` element. This is why your page has both scrollbars.

To get rid of it, you just add `margin: 0;` to your `body` CSS style.

```
body {
    background-color: black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0; /* add this line */
}
```

Comment: It was an unintentional typo. I have now changed it from `class` to `style`. Better?